# Accuracy of deriving the CDF using integration

Tags: python, math, scipy, floating-accuracy

I have two ways of deriving the probability of a normally (say) distributed random variable to be within an interval. The first and most straight-forward is the following:

```
import scipy.stats
print scipy.stats.norm.cdf(6) - scipy.stats.norm.cdf(5)
# 2.85664984223e-07
```

And the second is by integrating the **pdf**:

```
import scipy.integrate
print scipy.integrate.quad(scipy.stats.norm.pdf, 5, 6)[0]
# 2.85664984234e-07
```

The difference in this case is really tiny, but it doesn't mean it can't grow larger for other distributions or integration limits. Can you tell which is more accurate and why?

By the way, the first alternative seems to be at least 10 times faster, so if it is also more accurate (which would be my guess, since it is somewhat specialized), then it is perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, given those particular numbers, the `quad` approach will actually be more accurate.  The CDF itself can be computed quickly and accurately, of course, but look at the actual numbers:

```
>>> scipy.stats.norm.cdf(6), scipy.stats.norm.cdf(5)
(0.9999999990134123, 0.99999971334842808)
```

When you're differencing two very similar quantities, you lose accuracy.  Similar problems can be mitigated somewhat during integration if the coders are careful with their summations.

Anyway, we can check this against a high-resolution calculation using `mpmath`:

```
>>> via_cdf = scipy.stats.norm.cdf(6)-scipy.stats.norm.cdf(5)
>>> via_quad = scipy.integrate.quad(scipy.stats.norm.pdf, 5, 6)[0]
>>> import mpmath
>>> mpmath.mp.dps = 100
>>> def cdf(x): return 0.5 * (1 + mpmath.erf(x/mpmath.sqrt(2)))
>>> highres = cdf(6)-cdf(5)
>>> highres
mpf('0.0000002856649842341562135330514687422473118357532223619105443630157837185833042478210791954518847897468442097')
>>> float((highres - via_quad)/highres)
-2.3824773334590333e-16
>>> float((highres - via_cdf)/highres)
3.86659439572868e-11
```

Comment: The other option here is to use the survival function: `norm.sf(5) - norm.sf(6)`, which seems to give accuracy somewhere between the two results above.

Comment: Wait, I take that back: it gives accuracy *better* than either the cdf computation or the quadrature result

Comment: I fully agree with Mark. **Never** use the wrong tail of a symmetric distribution if you want tail probabilities. I get a difference to the mpmath results of -6.3527471044072525e-22 for Marks sf version. see for example https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2477 or similar

Answer (score 0):

The first calls an implementation of the cdf included in `scipy.special`. The latter actually does the integration. The former is probably more accurate (as it is limited only by the computer's ability do evaluate the CDF and not by any errors introduced by numerical integration). In practice, unless you need results that are good to better than 6 decimal places, you're probably fine.